# Format Date in Display Tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

Im using Struts2 and Display tag library.

```
<display:table name="list" pagesize="3">
    <display:column property="date" title="DATE" />         
</display:table>
```

How to format the date column above? e.g. m/d/yyyy

Comment: Use [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
<display:table name="list" pagesize="3">
    <display:column property="date" title="DATE" format="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" /> 
</display:table>
```

Comment: perfect! :-). what does 0 stands for?

Comment: format has the format = { <var position>, <type>, <pattern> }, where <var position> is 0 for first variable.  It's consistent to Java messages convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:table name="${dao.lista()}" pagesize="5">
    <display:column property="id"/>
    <display:column property="nome" />
    <display:column property="email" />
    <display:column property="endereco" />                                                      
    <display:column property="dataNascimento.time" title="DATE" format="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"/>                                        
</display:table>
```

Comment: Same as the approved answer.